# What is the best way to handle large inputs in python (100 k lines)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input

I need to handle input of 100k lines (each line contains a string) and perform a function on each line. The function will return one result per string and should print it to the console. 
What is the best way of doing this?

My current attempt is:

```
strings = []
for i in xrange(int(input())):
    strings.append(raw_input())
```

More background: I want to solve a problem on Hackerrank. An input can look like this (powered by Hackerrank):
https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/4187/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINGOTNJCTGAUP7NA&Expires=1420719780&Signature=iSzA93z7GKVIcn4NvdqAbbCOfMs%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: You should tell us what you want to do with the lines after you have read them.

Comment: First question, you should ask yourself here: Do you really need all the data in memory **at the same time** ?

Comment: You want to store 100k lines in a single list at one time? Are you sure that this is the most efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Edited my question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store the entire file in memory because you are calculating and printing results as you read the file.

As such, simply read the file line-by-line, do your calculations and print the results:

```
with open('large-file.txt') as the_file:
    for line in the_file:
       result = do_something_with(line)
       print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the stdin stream, the stdin is like a file stream

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin
  do_work(line)
```

Comment: How is the end of a file indicated?

Comment: when the stdin receives null byte this is done automatically by hackerrank inputs